# When would I want to create an Object that implements Collection (or one of its sub-interfaces)

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I am an intermediate-level Java programmer without any professional experience. I am wondering what the practical applications are of creating a specialized Object that implements Collection. For what reasons would one do this rather than simply using an existing Object like a LinkedList, HashSet, Queue, etc...?

Thanks!

Comment: Note about terminology: you're confusing object and class. new ArrayList<>() creates a object. Creating a class, OTOH consists in writing code like `class Foo implements Collection<...>`. Regarding your question: one would do this when one wants a specific behavior that doesn't exist in any of the standard collections. Many libraries have additional collection implementations, like immutable collections for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *many* different implementations of `Collection`, each with their own special characteristics.

If you need a Collection with a different characteristic than any of the standard implementations in the Java Runtime Library, then you'd need to implement your own (or find a third-party library that already did it).

E.g. look at [Apache Commons Collections™](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/), or the collections in [Guava](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/package-summary.html) for examples of collections with "non-standard" characteristics.